# Sort all RecyclerView data

Tags: android, arraylist, android-recyclerview

I want to sort all recycler view data using anandroid Menu options.

On Main Activity, I use this:

```
companion object
{
    var items = ArrayList<BookContent.BookItem>()
    init
    {
        items.add(BookContent.BookItem(0, "Title 2", "Albert", Date(), "Description 2", ""))
        items.add(BookContent.BookItem(1, "Title 4", "Joan", Date(), "Description 4", ""))
        items.add(BookContent.BookItem(0, "Title 1", "Laura", Date(), "Description 1", ""))
        items.add(BookContent.BookItem(1, "Title 15", "Valeria", Date(), "Description 15", ""))
        items.add(BookContent.BookItem(0, "Title 6", "Jensen", Date(), "Description 6", ""))
        items.add(BookContent.BookItem(1, "Title 27", "Fran", Date(), "Description 27", ""))
        items.add(BookContent.BookItem(0, "Title 32", "Tim", Date(), "Description 32", ""))
        items.add(BookContent.BookItem(1, "Title 3", "James", Date(), "Description 3", ""))
        items.add(BookContent.BookItem(0, "Title 8", "Marie", Date(), "Description 8", ""))
        items.add(BookContent.BookItem(1, "Title 9", "Marta", Date(), "Description 9", ""))
        items.add(BookContent.BookItem(0, "Title 44", "Eli", Date(), "Description 44", ""))
    }
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean
{
    items = when (item.itemId)
    {
        R.id.sort_author -> items.sortedWith(compareBy({it.author},{it.author})) as ArrayList<BookContent.BookItem>
        R.id.sort_title -> items.sortedWith(compareBy({it.title},{it.title})) as ArrayList<BookContent.BookItem>
        else -> ArrayList<BookContent.BookItem>()
    }

    viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

But I obtain the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be
>   cast to java.util.ArrayList

I create the adapter on method onCreate:

```
viewManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
viewAdapter = SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(items)
recyclerView = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.book_recycler_view).apply {
    layoutManager = viewManager
    adapter = viewAdapter
}
```

Otherwise, is this the correct way of updating data?

Comment: Could you post the way you're initializing the `items` element.

Comment: Updated with the items initialization

Comment: is there a specific reason why you are using an `ArrayList` and not just the Kotlin `MutableList`? That way you don't need to worry about casting, and let Kotlin deal with the actual implementation of its `MutableList`.

Comment: With MutableList works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of worrying about casting, it would be much simpler to use Kotlin's `List` directly here, and let Kotlin worry about the underlying classes it uses. You can do this as follows:

```
companion object
{
    // Note: I've also combined the list declaration and instantiation into one here
    var items = listOf(
        BookContent.BookItem(0, "Title 2", "Albert", Date(), "Description 2", ""), 
        ...
    )
}

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean
{
    items = when (item.itemId)
    {
        // Note: I use sortedBy() instead or sortedWith() here to avoid needing to create 
        //  a Comparator, and because you're comparing the same property on each object. 
        //  I haven't tested this, but I'm fairly certain this would work the same as what you have
        R.id.sort_author -> items.sortedBy { it.author }
        R.id.sort_title -> items.sortedBy { it.title }
        else -> listOf()
    }

    viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

If you need it to be a mutable list (like `ArrayList`), then you can use `MutableList` instead. But here `List` would do the job.

**Edit - March 15, 2019**

In order to use the same adapter instead of creating a new one every time you need to update the list, simply add an `update()` method to your adapter that sets its internal list of items. I don't know exactly what your adapter looks like, but I would assume you could modify it to look like this:

```
class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(private var items: List<BookContent.BookItem>) {

    ...

    fun update(newItems: List<BookContent.BookItem>) {
        // Update the list of items used by the adapter
        items = newItems
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }
}
```

Then, in your activity:

```
override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean) {
    ...
    viewAdapter.update(items)
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
}
```

This way you don't need to create a new adapter every time, you just use the same one.

Comment: Everything ok, but `viewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` doesn't update the recycler view list. I have to create a new viewAdapter with the new sortedList and reasign the adapter to the recyclerView.

Comment: If you add your adapter creation code I can take a look.

Comment: Edited my answer. I took a guess as to how `SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter` looks like, if it doesn't look similar to what I put in just add that code to the question and I'll fix my answer. But I believe it's straightforward enough for you to understand what I'm doing!